# dictionary nested from dataframe for credencials streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, streamlit

I have a dataframe from panda (SQL) and i need to create credentials for streamlit.authenticator:

1. Script from sql database to dataframe (panda):

```
SELECT username as usernames,nome as name,HashPython as password FROM AspNetUsers WHERE HashPython is not null
```

2. Expected dictionary for streamlit.authenticator:

```
credentials = {
        "usernames":{
            "user@inv.com":{
                "name":"user1",
                "password":"12345"
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: `credentials = dict(usernames=df.set_index('usernames').to_dict(orient='index'))`?

Comment: Perfect anwser! thanks ouroboros. Please answer the question to close as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouroboros answered the question:

credentials = dict(usernames=df.set_index('usernames').to_dict(orient='index'))

Thanks!

Best regards.

Comment: You're welcome. Added the answer with the references as well as some dummy data. So, you can remove this answer :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to make `usernames` the index, and chain [`df.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with `orient` parameter set to `'index'`. Next, use the result inside a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) construction to assign to the `usernames` key:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'usernames': ['user@inv.com','user2@inv.com'],
        'name': ['user1','user2'],
        'password': ['12345','23456']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

credentials = dict(usernames=df.set_index('usernames').to_dict(orient='index'))

credentials

{'usernames': {'user@inv.com': {'name': 'user1', 'password': '12345'},
               'user2@inv.com': {'name': 'user2', 'password': '23456'}
               }
 }
```